# Deploying F# exe

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-data

I have an F# program I built in VS2013. I am intending to deploy this on a windows 2008 R2 server with .NET framework 4.5 installed. Now, when I build the program in visual studio, it creates an exe in the debug/bin directory (MyProgram.exe). Do I need to include a copy of fharp.core.dll with the exe? Or, will the build process automatically compile the necessary dependancy DLLs (fsharp.core, fsharp.data, fsharp.data.TypeProviders)? Most of the research I can search online for seems to look at VS2010 and I am not using fsc,exe currently.

Thanks for any insight provided.

Comment: You will need to coy all the files in the bin/debug folder to the deployment location.  Side note F# compiles down to MSIL, there is no difference in deploying a .Net application written in F# and one written in  C#

Comment: @theDarse That's not entirely correct. F# code uses types and functions defined in FSharp.Core (lists, options, etc.), and since FSharp.Core isn't part of the BCL, you have to make sure that this assembly is *somehow* available to the program that depends on these types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may or may not need to copy `FSharp.Core.dll` together with the `.exe`.

If F# is already installed on the server, you may not need it, but it has to be the correct version of F#.

Otherwise, the F# license allows you to deploy FSharp.Core.dll together with your own binaries.

There's also the 'official' [FSharp.Core NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/), if that's more to your liking.

Comment: I copied the fsharp.core.dll to the same directory where MyProgram.exe is. When it launches, I get an unhandled exception error "Missing method Eception: Microsoft.Fsharp.Control.FsharpAsync'1<System.IO.TextReader> FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncReadTextAtRuntime..." It runs perfectly fine in VS2013. I don't understand why this doesn't work. Thanks for helping

Comment: I can't say specifically what the problem is, but those *MissingMethodExceptions* are always (IME) because of assembly version mismatches. You have to make sure that the version of FSharp.Core.dll in the program's probing path is the same as the version against which it was compiled.

Comment: You may be able to use [Fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to troubleshoot the issue...

Comment: Thanks. The problem was resolved by recopying all the bin directory files once again. Thanks to theDarse as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the compiler option `--standalone` to statically links the FSharp.Core.dll (F# runtime) and any reference assemblies that depend on it (i.e. any other F# assemblies).

Comment: Where the heck would I add this option in a VS F# project?  Seemingly nothing relevant in project -> options -> build

Comment: In the test field "other flags" in project -> properties -> build